# Can we represent matrix $\ A_{2x2}$ like this $\ A=\lambda_1R_1+\lambda_2R_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\ A\in{M_{2x2}}$ with $\ \lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ \lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ as eigenvalues

Prove that matrix$\ A$ can be represented like: $\ A_{2x2}$ like this $\ A=\lambda_1R_1+\lambda_2R_2$

We know that $\ R_1^2=R_1,\ R_2^2=R_2,\ R_1+R_2=I,\ R_1R_2=0$

I have tried finding some relation between matrices $\ R_1,R_2$ by taking two matrices $\ R_1=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ and $\ R_2=\pmatrix{x&y\\z&w}$ and solving system of equations that we get from their relations that are given to us in the problem statement but that wasn't very useful to me.

Comment: are you sure $A$ is not assumed to be symmetric?

Comment: Doesn't say in the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve described a pair of projections. The idea behind this decomposition is that since $A$ is diagonalizable, you can decompose $\mathbb R^2$ into the direct sum of the eigenspaces $E_1$ and $E_2$ of $A$ that correspond to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. This lets you decompose $A$ into a linear combination of projections onto those subspaces.

We know that we can write any vector $\mathbf v\in\mathbb R^2$ as $\mathbf v_1+\mathbf v_2$, where $\mathbf v_1\in E_1$ and $\mathbf v_2\in E_2$. By the definition of eigenvector, $A\mathbf v=\lambda_1\mathbf v_1+\lambda_2\mathbf v_2$. Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be linear maps (as yet unknown) such that $R_1\mathbf v=\mathbf v_1$ and $R_2\mathbf v=\mathbf v_2$. It should be clear that $R_1+R_2=I$. Then $A\mathbf v=\lambda_1R_1\mathbf v+\lambda_2R_2\mathbf v$, i.e., $A=\lambda_1R_1+\lambda_2R_2$. This gives us the decomposition of $A$ that we wanted.

Suppose that $\mathbf v\in E_2$. Then its component $\mathbf v_1$ in the above direct-sum decomposition is zero, which means that $R_1\mathbf v=0$. But for any vector $\mathbf v$, $R_2\mathbf v\in E_2$, therefore $R_1R_2=0$. By symmetry, we also have $R_2R_1=0$.

Now examine $A^2\mathbf v$. We have $$\begin{align}A^2\mathbf v&=(\lambda_1R_1+\lambda_2R_2)^2\mathbf v\\&=\lambda_1^2R_1^2\mathbf v+\lambda_1\lambda_2(R_1R_2+R_2R_1)\mathbf v+\lambda_2^2R_2^2\mathbf v\\&=\lambda_1^2R_1^2\mathbf v+\lambda_2^2R_2^2\mathbf v\end{align}$$ but we also know that $$A^2\mathbf v=A^2(\mathbf v_1+\mathbf v_2)=\lambda_1^2\mathbf v_1+\lambda_2^2\mathbf v_2=\lambda_1^2R_1\mathbf v+\lambda_2^2R_2\mathbf v.$$ Comparing these two expansions, we can see that one way to make them equal is to require that $R_1^2=R_1$, $R_2^2=R_2$. These conditions say that these maps are projections and by the way we’ve defined them, they’re projections onto the eigenspaces $E_1$ and $E_2$, respectively.

We now have enough to construct $R_1$ and $R_2$ explicitly. Recall that by definition $E_1=\ker(A-\lambda_1I)$ and $E_2=\ker(A-\lambda_2I)$ so these seem like possible starting points for our two projections. We have $$\begin{align}(A-\lambda_1I)\mathbf v&=A\mathbf v-\lambda_1\mathbf v\\&=(\lambda_1\mathbf v_1+\lambda_2\mathbf v_2)-(\lambda_1\mathbf v_1+\lambda_1\mathbf v_2)\\&=(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)\mathbf v_2\in E_2\end{align}$$ so the kernel and image of this map match what we want for $R_2$. To end up with $\mathbf v_2$, divide by $\lambda_2-\lambda_1$, i.e., $$R_2={A-\lambda_1I\over\lambda_2-\lambda_1}$$ and again by symmetry, $$R_1={A-\lambda_2I\over\lambda_1-\lambda_2}.$$ To check that these are in fact projections, we compute $$\begin{align}(A-\lambda_1)^2\mathbf v&=(A-2\lambda_1A+\lambda_1^2I)\mathbf v\\&=(\lambda_1^2\mathbf v_1+\lambda_2^2\mathbf v_2)-2(\lambda_1^2\mathbf v_1+\lambda_1\lambda_2\mathbf v_2)+(\lambda_1^2\mathbf v_1+\lambda_1^2\mathbf v_2)\\&=(\lambda_2^2-2\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_2^2)\mathbf v_2\\&=(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)^2\mathbf v_2\\&=(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)^2R_2\mathbf v\end{align}$$ therefore $R_2^2=R_2$. I’ll leave verifying the rest to you.

Going back to the expansion of $A^2$ shows why this decomposition is useful. It’s easy to see from it that $A^n=\lambda_1^nR_1+\lambda_2^nR_2$. (You can also show this directly by applying the Binomal theorem and noting that all mixed terms vanish.) Thus, we have a simple way to compute powers of $A$ without ever having to find an eigenvector or perform any matrix multiplications, which we’d need to do if computing powers by diagonalizing $A$ instead. It turns out that, at least for $2\times2$ matrices, there are similar short cuts for computing powers (and exponentials) of these matrices for the cases of repeated eigenvalues and complex eigenvalues as well.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** the previous answer contained a mistake: the assumption that the eigenvectors are orthogonal, which they don't have to be for this to work. Thanks to [Joppy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/431940/joppy) for pointing it out!

OK, so the correct things to say are the following: let $v_1,v_2$ be the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ respectively. Then they are linearly independent, since everything in the span of $v_1$ has eigenvalue $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$ and vice versa. Thus every vector admits a unique decomposition $v=\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2v_2$.

Now consider the operators $R_i$ which project such a vector $v$ to $\alpha_iv_i$. Then clearly $R_i^2=R_i$ since once you're in the span of $v_i$, $R_i$ does nothing. Moreover, $R_1+R_2=I$ by construction, and finally, composing $R_1R_2$ is the zero operator, since once you project on the span of $v_2$, your $v_1$-component is $0$.

Finally, $A=\lambda_1R_1 + \lambda_2R_2$. This uses the principle that 'a matrix is what a matrix does' (which is pretty useful in linear algebra in general). Namely, to show that $A$ equals this other matrix, it suffices to show that this other matrix acts like $A$ on the two independent eigenvectors, which is straightforward.

Comment: Why is it a special case of the spectral theorem? Where is the self-adjointness? I think most of your answer is still correct, but you cannot assume the eigenvectors are orthogonal.

Comment: oh dang, I guess it's true that the orthogonality proof uses the fact that the operator is self-adjoint doesn't it? Then doesn't that imply that the statement (really, the $R_1R_2=0$ part) can be false for non-symmetric matrices?

Comment: No, it still works. $R_1$ and $R_2$ should be the projections onto the $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ eigenspaces, respectively. But not orthogonal projections, you shouldn't need to mention the inner product at all.

Comment: But why would $R_1R_2=0$ if the eigenspaces are not orthogonal?

Comment: Let $v_1,v_2$ be the eigenvectors. I'm talking about the projections that take $a v_1 + b v_2$ to $a v_1$, and $b v_2$.

Comment: Finally, if you know the diagonalisation $A = P D P^{-1}$, where $D = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$, the matrix of $A_1$ will be $P E_1 P^{-1}$, where $E_1 = \mathrm{diag}(1, 0)$, and similarly for $A_2$. So you can view a diagonalisation as encoding these projections directly.